# PHP. HTML. Гиперссылки

Tags: php, html

Есть код

```
echo "<body>
        <p><a href="images/xxx.jpg">Посмотрите на мою фотографию!</a></p>      
        <p><a href="tip.html">Как сделать такое же фото?</a></p> 
      </body>";
```

Все работает. Но ***как в php файле проверить была ли нажата гиперссылка?
И если одна из гиперссылок была нажата, то какая из них именно?***

Comment: А зачем это нужно?

Comment: может стоит подключить yandex.metrica или gtm к примеру

Comment: можно отлавливать js -ом в принципе

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['image'])){
    include 'images/xxx.jpg';
    exit();
}
if(isset($_GET['tip'])){
    include 'tip.html';
    exit();
}
echo "<body>
<p><a href='?image'>Посмотрите на мою фотографию!</a></p>
<p><a href='?tip'>Как сделать такое же фото?</a></p>
</body>";
```

Comment: А если там ссылка на сайт? вместо image?

Comment: тогда GET поможет?

Comment: <a href='images/xxx.jpg?image'> разве что так,но тогда include не нужен

Comment: понятно спасибо